# Hi, i have an problem with the inversion of data on a table

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, cursor

I'm basically having a problem reversing data on a table. I would like to invert both fields of a table first name and last name, I have created a slider for the data to scroll and as an attribute of the cursor I used %rowtype so that I get the whole string back.
I attach the error that I get [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEG1V.png)

```
      declare
    v_inversione nominativi%rowtype;
    cursor nominativi_cur is
    select nominativi from nominativi
    for update;
         begin
        open nominativi_cur;
     loop
        fetch nominativi_cur into v_inversione
       exit when nominativi_cur%notfound;
       update nominativi set nome = v_inversione.cognome
    end loop;
   end;
 /
```

Answer (score 1):

Please paste the error as text into the question. Links can potentially be harmful.

Read the error in detail - it's in English here:

```
ORA-06550: line 10, column 5: 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXIT" when expecting one of the following:
    := . ( @ % ;
```

So... on line 10, column 5 the compiler found a string "EXIT" but it was expecting one of the following characters: ":= . ( @ % ;".

Lines 8,9,10 are:

```
8     loop
9        fetch nominativi_cur into v_inversione
10       exit when nominativi_cur%notfound;
```

You can see the "exit" keyword on line 10. The error happens because line 9 is not terminated by a semi-colon (;)

Change it to

```
8     loop
9        fetch nominativi_cur into v_inversione;
10       exit when nominativi_cur%notfound;
```

and it should compile without this error.